# ASP MVC combining views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Still new to ASP MVC development.
Suppose I have a MusicController that has 2 views: List (which shows a list of all artists) and Highlights (which shows 3 specific albums with all details).

I now want to render both views on one page.
    1) What is the best way to do this? Partial views? Do I need to make a separate controller for the page that shows both partial views?
    2) Suppose I want to change the highlights based on the selected artist. How to pass that parameter  to the partial view with highlights?

Thanks for giving me some leads!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial views is indeed what you want.  One bit of trouble that you might run into is that sometimes it's hard to make a partial view that works as both stand-alone and embedded in another view.  The solution is to create a separate view that contains all the necessary boilerplate that then calls the (single) partial view.  Then the partial views are suitable to be used in both the individual pages and the combined page.

You don't need a separate controller for your aggregate view, but it will need its own action.

So here's the structure I'm advocating:

In `MusicController`:

```
public ActionResult List() {
  return View();
}
public ActionResult Highlights() {
  return View();
}
public ActionResult ListAndHighlights() {
  return View();
}
```

The views for `List` and `Highlights` would look something like this:

```
<div class="anyNecessaryChrome">
  @RenderPartial( "ListPartial" )
</div>
```

And `ListAndHighlights()` would look something like this:

```
<div class="listChrome">
  @RenderPartial( "ListPartial" )
</div>
<div class="highlightsChrome">
  @RenderPartial( "HighlightsPartial" )
</div>
```

If you want the partial views to update in response to something on the client side, you'll have to use AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`Html.RenderAction()` and `Html.RenderPartial()`](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx)

Alternatively I would have the List of Artists as a View and load the Highlights using AJAX.

**For that you need just 2 Action Methods**

```
public class ArtistsController {
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**and**

```
public class AlbumsController {
    [HttpGet]
    public JSONResult GetHighlights(int artistId) {
        return JSON(Albums.GetHighlights(artistId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**And some sample HTML**

```
<ul id="artists">
   <li><a href="#" data-artist-id="1">Michael Jackson</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-artist-id="2">Tom Jones</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Then you can call your Highlights action method using jQuery's `$.get`**

```
$("#artists a").click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data("artist-id");
    $.get("/Albums/GetHighlights/" + id, function(data) {
        // Populate highlights section with data from server
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ViewModel for this which stores a list of Artist and List of Albums

```
public class ArtistWithHighlights
{
  public Artist Artist { set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<Albums> Albums{ set;get;}
}
```

And in the Controlller, write an action method for the GET view. In that Get all Artists and Get the Albums belongs to the first Artist. (you can change this according to your requirement)

```
public ActionResult ArtistsWithHighLights()
{
  List<ArtistWithHighlights> allArtists=new List<ArtistWithHighlights>();
  allArtists=GetAllArtists();

  //If we have atlease one artist in the list, Load the albums for the first one only
  if(allArtists.Count>0)
  {
     allArtists[0].Albums=GetAlbumsForArtist(allArtists[0].Artist.ArtistID);
  }    
  return View(allArtists);       
}
```

and your strongly typed view is like this

```
@model List<ArtistWithHighlights>

@foreach(var artist in Model)
{
  <a id="@artist.ID" class="artistName">@artist.Name</p>
}
<div id="albums">
  <h3>Highlighted Albums</h3>
  @foreach(var album in Model[0].Albums)
  {
     <p>@album.Name</p>
  }
</div>
```

For getting the Albums of another Artist on selection (a click event), You can make an ajax call to another `Action` method which returns a list of Albums for the passed artist id and then you can show that in the div.

```
$(function(){
 $(".artistName").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   var  artistId=$(this.attr("id");
     $("#albums").load("../Albums/"+artistId);
  });
});
```