# Problems combining AspNetCore MVC Views together on one view page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The main problem I'm having is a Null Reference Exception (detailed below) in form code with a Select Tag Helper. However, I'm seeking advice for the overall approach dor including multiple views together on a page, too.

I’ve looked at different ways to combine multiple views on a single view page. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727795/asp-mvc-combining-views) uses if-else choices for layout and RenderPartial for Partial Views with separate controllers/actions and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727795/asp-mvc-combining-views) is similar with dependency on AJAX for clientside responsiveness that I don’t know if I want or need in a reference implementation. I’ve also looked at other suggested search results that didn’t come as close as these two.

So, I’ve looked and I’ve tried the two following approaches using the code I worked out for selecting and displaying single page view results for each of four data categories from a specific db record. The four data categories need to added together in turn to the overall message page because this page is for assembling the overall CAP message. I will then use it again in the “Review Message” and the “Approve Message” pages—which is the finish line for this first EDXL (Emergency Data Exchange Language) project (Hallelujah!)

Here is first try, using the same code used to select the record which I want to display the details of the Alert category of the overall Message.

```
@model edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.EdxlCapMessageViewModel
. . .
@{
<h4>Alert</h4>

<div class="select_container">
    <form asp-controller="Alerts" asp-action="Details" method="post">
        <select class="cap_select" id="cap_select" style="width:100%;max-width:95%;"
        asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="@Model.Alert_Identifiers">
            <option>Select one</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="Details" value="LoadAlert" />
    </form>
</div>
}
```

However, I’m getting a Null Reference Exception on the line: `asp-for=”SelectedAlertIndex” asp-items=”@Model.Alert_Identifiers”>`. The only difference between this code and the code that successfully retrieves and displays the Alert category in a table on the Index.cshtml page is that this one references the `asp-action=”Details”` rather than Index.

If I can get this version to work, there are three more virtually identical code blocks for the other data categories.

The other approach I tried uses one of these same code blocks in each of  four separate partial views on single page using a custom layout for this “Assemble.cshtml” view page using the EdxlCapMessageViewModelsController. Needless to say, I still have the same Null Reference Exception, and I’m not seeing how to overcome this. For this second version I use the minimal action method in the EdxlCapMessageViewModelsController:

```
public IActionResult Assemble()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

It was suggested that show the controller code for the Details action:

```
// GET: Alerts/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var alert = await _context.Alert
            //.Include(e => e.Elements)
            //    .ThenInclude(d=> d.DataCategory)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AlertIndex == id);

        if (alert == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(alert);
    }
```

But I also would really appreciate some feedback on the best way approach this problem. I'm adding `EdxlCapMessageViewModel.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using edxl_cap_v1_2.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels
{
    public class EdxlCapMessageViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int AlertIndex { get; set; }
    public string Alert_Identifier { get; set; }
    public int SelectedAlertIndex { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<SelectListItem> Alert_Identifiers { get; set; }
    public List<AlertVm> Alerts { get; set; }

    public Alert Alert { get; set; }

    public Info Info { get; set; }

    public Area Area { get; set; }

    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
}

}
```

This is the stack trace from the Browser:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCore._Views_EdxlCapMessageViewModels_Assemble_cshtml+<<ExecuteAsync>b__20_1>d.MoveNext() in Assemble.cshtml
+ 19.    asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="Model.Alert_Identifiers">
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext+<GetChildContentAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper+<ProcessAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner+<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
AspNetCore._Views_EdxlCapMessageViewModels_Assemble_cshtml+<ExecuteAsync>d__20.MoveNext() in Assemble.cshtml
+ 4    Layout = null;
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderPageCoreAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderPageAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult+<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+ 
<InvokeResultAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecuted-Context context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(Resource-ExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPoint-Middleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPage-Middleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPage-Middleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugger-Notification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: The `asp-items` doesn't need the `@` - it should be `asp-items="Model.Alert_Identifiers"`.  Are you certain that a) the model is populated and passed to the view, and b) the `Alert_Identifiers` property is set?  The code for the controller action that displays this view would be helpful in your question too

Comment: Thanks @Brendan Green. I removed unneeded `@` from `asp-items`. The model is apparently not populated, but that also holds true for form code used in other data category pages and those succeed. I added the controller code for the `Details()` action at the end of the question. The successful code is for `Index()` action, but when I change this one to Index I still get the Null Reference Exception.

Comment: Please post the `EdxlCapMessageViewModel` class definition, and some more detail on the exception that you are getting (i.e. the stacktrace and message out of the debugger).

Comment: Thanks @Brendan Green. Added `EdxlCapMessageViewModel.cs` and stack trace from browser. Right now despite checking the Null Exception box under Common Language Runtime Exceptions, the debugger isn't breaking when exception is thrown. I'll have to come back to this in the morning.

Comment: I still think that's because your model (`@Model`) is null.  You probably want the controller action to pass in a default model instance, or construct an appropriate model.

Comment: Thanks Again @Brendan Green. Your insights helped me. I resolved the problem, which I will describe in an answer soon. Many thanks.

Comment: @Brendan Green, you might want to look at the partial answer below because I got another Null Reference Exception on a file that is identical to another that works-wicked problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the first problem by changing the code to AlertPick.cshtml:

```
@model edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.AlertViewModel

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "AlertPick";
}

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>

@{
    <h4>@Model.Alerts.Count Alerts</h4>

    <form asp-controller="Alerts" asp-action="PickAlert" method="post">
        <select class="cap_select" id="cap_select" style="width:100%;max-width:95%;"
        asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="Model.Alert_Identifiers">
            <option>Select one</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="PickAlert" value="Pick Alert to Assemble EDXL-Cap Message" />
    </form>
}
```

This renders a page with the Alert_Identifiers as options in a dropdownlist to select from and which, once chosen, takes viewer to a Details page for that alert data category when the submit button "Pick Alert to Assemble EDXL-CAP Message" is clicked.

This is the behavior I want, but what I want now is to have this same behavior four times down a view page that collects all data categories for the complete EDXL-CAP message. However, when I copy AlertPick.cshtml as _AlertPick.cshtml for a partial view and collect the set of four partial views into Assemble.cshtml, an otherwise blank page using a layout page that displays the four partial views I don't get the result I'm looking for...

When I do this, the first partial view throws another Null Reference Exception, on the `<h4>@Model.Alerts.Count Alerts</h4>` line first, and also on `asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="Model.Alert_Identifiers">` when I comment out that first line. And it does this even though AlertPick.cshtml above is identical to _AlertPick.cshtml. So the overall problem is only 1/4 solved, and that's as much of an answer as I have as of 09-14-2018. Any help would be welcome, but the first part is solved and how to do the rest may need to be another question unless I manage to solve it on my own.